# Powershell: Filling current row with color in Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-ise

Been working with Powershell script which runs a loop against a bunch of machines and generates an Excel spreadsheet with the results using a foreach loop - would like to fill the color of a row based on a certain criteria. I don't have any PC's currently that meet this criteria so I cant test, wondering if someone could tell me if I have the code right in the last like to fill the current row.

```
$a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$a.visible = $True
$b = $a.Workbooks.Add()
$c = $b.Worksheets.Item(1)
$c.rows($_).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd do this:

```
$a.ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

Comment: I finally earned enough priviledge mark as useful and answer, so wanted to say thanks - I modified in my script and it's working like this: $c.Range("$($intRow):$($intRow)").interior.colorindex = 6